# 2013 Honda Civic battery hold down bracket plastic cap wont come off

Tags: honda, battery, civic

I'm trying to replace the battery on my 2013 Honda Civic. I gotta take off the hold down bracket but there is a little cap on top of the bracket nut that's keeping the cables (needlessly) secure. Before I do what I'd usually do, break it off, I was wondering if there is a trick in removing this cap? I tried pulling very hard on it and tried using a plier and squeezing the cap and pulling up. Nothing.

Here's a picture:

[image]

I tried looking online but I can't find anything about it. Maybe because I don't know what that cap is really called. There is a youtube of a battery replacement for the previous Civic model and all he did was pull on it, I tried that, hard, again nothing. Really irks me when car manufacturers do things like this :-(

Comment: What is it made out of? Plastic/Metal? It looks like it is hex-shaped, so have you tried rotating it off with a socket wrentch?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like. So that's what I tried. What that does is to break the plastic. That hex cap is just a cover. There's another layer below that that can screw off once that's broken off. I think on a new car, the think is just pushed on. I'll be looking at something else now to hold down the wires. That's all it's there for.

Answer (score 2):

Just grab hold of it and pull up while wiggling it back and forth. It should come right up. [Please view this video](https://youtu.be/_xEO389DOc8) as he shows exactly what I mean about 30 seconds in. Don't be afraid of it, just get in there and do it.

Comment: *insert Shia Lebouf gif* just do it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally this plug comes off by pulling, probably the plug is fused on to the threads due to heat, try pulling with pliers. If it does not comes out break it by tapping in it with a hammer (only the centre bit) and later  replace it with a steel nut and some washers. Preserve the plastic clamp (the outer ring )that is holding the wires, dont break it .

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to pull it off with my hand until I took a 10mm socket with a racheting wrench to it to loosen up the connection. I did not hear any snapping or anything sounding like a break when I did this and now I can pull it off easily and put it back on.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you don't even need to remove the black cap. If you remove the anchor on the front side if the battery, you can pull the battery out.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs to replace the clip/harness strap, it is the same part for many Honda vehicles through the years.

The part number is:  91531-S5B-003